# HTML Video tag just shows half the video in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html5-video

I have been working on a project in which I had to replicate exactly https://www.google.com/atap/project-jacquard/

The video tag that I have used to play a background video, displays only half in Internet Explorer, but works just fine with other browsers. The version if IE I have is 11.0 . Following is the screenshot

[image: This is the screenshot from IE]

I tried hard, but can't put my finger exactly on where am I going wrong. I'd appreciate if someone could help me find my mistake...

Also, the footer is not being responsive.

Here is my entire code ->

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Project Jacquard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/yes.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>


            <img id="img1" src="img/jacquard-row.svg" alt="Project Jacquard" class="ri" style=""><!--  width:22.5%; -->
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <header class="header-image">
        <div class="headline" style="height: 850px;">

            <div class="container" id="content">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Technology woven in.</h2>
                <button class="centerButton">Play Film</button>

            </div>

            <video class="vid" autoplay loop controls muted> <!--  id="bgvid"  style="width:1349; height:600;" -->
                <source src="video/Jacquard.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <img id="alternative" src="alternative.jpg" />
            </video> 
             <iframe style="margin-top: 60px;" class="vid" id="yt" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qObSFfdfe7I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">


        <!-- Second Featurette -->
        <div class="featurette" id="services">
            <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">Introducing Project Jacquard</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left" src="img/1.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Project Jacquard makes it possible to weave touch and gesture interactivity into any textile using standard, industrial looms.</p>
            <br />
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Everyday objects such as clothes and furniture can be transformed into interactive surfaces.</p>
        </div>



        <!-- Third Featurette -->
        <div class="featurette" id="contact" style="padding-top: 50px;">
           <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;"> Spinning conductive yarns</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-right" src="img/2.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">This is possible thanks to new conductive yarns, created in collaboration with our industrial partners.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Jacquard yarn structures combine thin, metallic alloys with natural and synthetic yarns like cotton, polyester, or silk, making the yarn strong enough to be woven on any industrial loom.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Jacquard yarns are indistinguishable from the traditional yarns that are used to produce fabrics today.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="featurette" id="services"></div>

         <div class="featurette" id="services" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">Weaving interactive textiles</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left" src="img/3.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left" src="img/4.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Using conductive yarns, bespoke touch and gesture-sensitive areas can be woven at precise locations, anywhere on the textile.</p>
            <br />
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Alternatively, sensor grids can be woven throughout the textile, creating large, interactive surfaces.</p>
        </div>

         <div class="featurette" id="contact" style="padding-top: 50px;">
           <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;"> Embedding electronics</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-right" src="img/5.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-right" src="img/6.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">The complementary components are engineered to be as discreet as possible. We developed innovative techniques to attach the conductive yarns to connectors and tiny circuits, no larger than the button on a jacket. These miniaturized electronics capture touch interactions, and various gestures can be inferred using machine-learning algorithms.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Captured touch and gesture data is wirelessly transmitted to mobile phones or other devices to control a wide range of functions, connecting the user to online services, apps, or phone features.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">LEDs, haptics, and other embedded outputs provide feedback to the user, seamlessly connecting them to the digital world.</p>
        </div>

         <div class="featurette" id="services" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">Producing at scale</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left" src="img/7.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left" src="img/8.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Jacquard components are cost-efficient to produce, and the yarns and fabrics can be manufactured with standard equipment used in mills around the world.</p>
            <br />
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">One loom can generate as many different textile designs as there are people on the planet. Now that same loom can also weave in interactivity.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="featurette" id="contact" style="padding-top: 50px;">
           <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;"> Making connected clothing</h2>
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-right" src="img/9.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-right" src="img/10.jpg" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Connected clothes offer new possibilities for interacting with services, devices, and environments. These interactions can be reconfigured at any time.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Jacquard is a blank canvas for the fashion industry. Designers can use it as they would any fabric, adding new layers of functionality to their designs, without having to learn about electronics.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">Developers will be able to connect existing apps and services to Jacquard-enabled clothes and create new features specifically for the platform.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;">We are also developing custom connectors, electronic components, communication protocols, and an ecosystem of simple applications and cloud services.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="featurette" id="services" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">Project Jacquard will allow designers and <br> developers to build connected, touch-sensitive <br>textiles into their own products.</h3>
         </div>

         <div class="featurette" id="contact" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <img src="img/jacquard-row.svg" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; padding-bottom: 10px; display: block;">

            <h4 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">Technology woven in.</h4>

        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
                    <img src="img/googleATAP.svg" style=" padding-left: 80px; float: left; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:10px;">
                    <div class="left">
                         <ul style="padding-left: 60px;">
                            <li style="padding-top:20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/">About Google</a></li>
                            <li style="padding-left: 50px; padding-top:20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/?fg=1">Privacy</a></li>
                            <li style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top:20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/regional.html">Terms</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </div>

                   <div class="right">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top:20px;">Follow Google ATAP:</li>
                        <li style="padding-right: 20px;"><a style="width: 40px;" href="https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+GoogleATAP/"><img src="img/gplus.svg"></a></li>
                        <li style="padding-right: 80px;"><a style="width: 40px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogATAP"><img src="img/youtube.svg"></a></li> 

                    </ul>

                   </div>

                   </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $("button").click(function () {
            $("#content").hide();
            $("#yt")[0].src += "?autoplay=1";
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#yt").show(); }, 200);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS file 1 ->

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    overflow-x:hidden; }

/*video {display: block;}*/

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; } }

.navbar-inverse {   background-color: #fff; }

.navbar {   min-height: 82px; }

img.ri {    position: absolute;     max-width: 80%;     top: 10%;   left: 10%;  border-radius: 3px;     /*box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);*/ }

img.ri:empty {  top: 50%;   left: 50%;  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   -o-transform: translate(-50%,
-50%);  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

video#bgvid { position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background-size: cover; }

.google-front-button{   border-radius: 0;   border: 2px solid #fff;   height: 50px;   line-height: 44px;   padding: 0 30px 2px;   text-transform: none;   transition: all .4s ease-in-out; }

.centerButton {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 145px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 1.2em/10px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 17px 10px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
    } /* a.centerButton {

    text-decoration: none; }
*/ a:hover {    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);     }

a.centerButton:hover {  text-decoration:none;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);     transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out; }

.headline {
    padding: 250px 0 1px 0; }

.headline h2 {  font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #fff;
    /*background: #fff;*/
    /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);*/ }

h2{
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px; }

.lead{
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: 300; }

.container {   width: auto; /*1170px*/ }

#contact{
    background-color: rgba(230,230,230,.8); }

h3{
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #676767; }

h4{
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black; }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; }


li{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px; }


a {
    font-family: "Karla",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    color:#676767; }

a:hover{
    color:#676767;
    text-decoration: underline; }

.left{
    float: left; }

.right{
    float: right; }

.vid {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover; }

#yt {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1; }

#content { }
```

Comment: try `width:100%;` for the footer with `text-align:center;` or `margin:auto;` for all the children elements. For the video, try using `-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`. Let me know if it works and I will make a full answer. I think this is your problem. I don't have an IE simulator so I can't test it. You haven't included all the browsers in the transform translate in your `.vid` class. This is what you have: `-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` You should have `-o-`, `-ms-`, and `-moz-` in addition.

Comment: Thanks man. Adding the other transforms did not help. Any more ideas? Maybe you'd like to save my code, and run it on your system and see? Cheers!

Comment: On phone right now; did you try width:100%; on the vid? Also try width:100vw;

Comment: Yup, just tried width:100%; and width:100vw; both right now again..no luck

Comment: Try doing overflow:auto; on the 'header-image' class and see if the video is just being cut off. Check to see if the `header-image` class is 100% (100vw) of the viewport width. Try adding `-ms-background-size: cover;` to the `header-image` too.

Comment: Try also doing something other then `cover`.

Comment: The only other "probable" value was fill.. and does not work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82652/discussion-between-codemode-and-www139).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer myself by playing with the code a bit. All i needed to do is add this 'particular' line to the .vid, for the IE translation

```
-ms-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-50%);
```

It covers up the screen all nice and good in IE too! Hope it helps someone who is stuck like i was! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code with the actual Project Jacquard page, it looks like you're missing a couple of styles from your CSS. To offset your translations, you need:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

NOTE: the top positioning might not be necessary. The Project Jacquard page doesn't have the Y translation, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.. just tried it. Does not work... :(

Comment: @codemode NOTE: `left` and `right` properties will work only when you apply `position` css properties with values `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

Comment: Hey +BurningLights, i don't want my bounty to get wasted. So i'll just let you have it...Cheers!

Comment: Gee, thanks!! That's really nice of you! Sorry I couldn't help you more.